# React post request after setState function doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, setstate

[image: 1]

The problem is API call executes before the setState function runs...

Is there anyway I can update the state first and send post request with the updated data??

Thanks!!

[image: 2]

I tried to use useEffect hook but it still didn't work...

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include code (and any errors) as text instead of as images

Comment: Also please share the exact error you get when using `useEffect`

Answer (score 0):

You're *very close* with your `handleSubmit()` function. Instead of trying to set the state using the state callback (not necessary here) and in the next line trying to access that set state (not possible/reliable), you can simply construct your new user's state, create the user, then set the user state.

**Instead of this:**

```
async function handleSubmit (event) {
  try {
    event.preventDefault();
    const id = Date.now();
    const joiningDate = await createJoiningDate();
    setUserInfo((prev) => ({ ...prev, id, joiningDate }));
    await createUser(userInfo, id, joiningDate);
    navigate(`/profile/54`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
}
```

**Use this:**

```
async function handleSubmit (event) {
  try {
    event.preventDefault();
    const id = Date.now();
    const joiningDate = await createJoiningDate();
    const newUserInfo = { ...userInfo, id, joiningDate };
    await createUser(newUserInfo, id, joiningDate);
    setUserInfo(newUserInfo);
    navigate(`/profile/54`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
}
```

Since your function is not occurring inside of a callback or useEffect, it should not have stale userInfo props so you can access it normally.

Setting state using the callback (`setUserInfo((prev) => ({ ...prev, id, joiningDate }));`) is a very good strategy when necessary.